# How can I manage my reactJS files in heroku server hosting?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-hosting

I am very well known for site deployment on Heroku server. But I only see how much memory used in my server. I can not see my files.

Comment: Run "heroku run bash --app=<your_app>" in your terminal. You can there inspect your files in the filesystem for your slug.

Comment: Here, I have run the command which suggests to you. But results look like this. command: 
  heroku run bash --app= react-tic-tac-toe-simple-game    Result:
 !    Flag --app expects a value